# If Else Error in CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am new to CoffeeScript and I am not sure why this code is not evaluating properly. I am getting SyntaxError: unexpected ELSE. What I am trying to do is dynamically update the rule_severity drop down based on the selection of the rule_log_type drop down.

```
jQuery ->
sev = $('#rule_severity').html()
$('#rule_log_type').change ->
    logtype = $('#rule_log_type :selected').text()
    if (logtype == 'Syslog')
        $('#rule_severity')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>')
        .append('<option value="Alert">Alert</option>')
        .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
        .append('<option value="Error">Error</option>')
        .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
        .append('<option value="Notice">Notice</option>')
        .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
        .val('Information')
    else if (logtype == 'Microsoft Windows')
        $('#rule_severity')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
        .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
        .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
        .val('Information')
```

Comment: A `switch` statement may be more suitable for your needs.... http://coffeescript.org/#switch

Comment: I tried using a switch initially and got a similar error.

Comment: Are you sure, that posted code contain error ? I tried it on http://coffeescript.org, adn can`t reproduce error.

Comment: I am not sure why but I get the error message with the if...else. I tried switch again and this time I have it working. Not sure why, maybe it had to do with my indentation. Good news is that switch is working.

Comment: Your code isn't indented, it's not actually running within the `jQuery ->` block. Your indentation is also a horrific mix of spaces and tabs. Choose one, and stick to it, or developing in CoffeeScript will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code. I think indentation is very key in CoffeeScript.

```
JQuery ->
sev = $('#rule_severity').html()
$('#rule_log_type').change ->
    logtype = $('#rule_log_type :selected').text()
    switch logtype
        when 'Syslog'
            console.log(logtype)
            $('#rule_severity')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>')
            .append('<option value="Alert">Alert</option>')
            .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
            .append('<option value="Error">Error</option>')
            .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
            .append('<option value="Notice">Notice</option>')
            .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
            .val('Information')
        when 'Microsoft Windows'
            console.log(logtype)
            $('#rule_severity')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
            .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
            .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
            .val('Information')
```

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be a `else if` instead of a `else`.

```
else if logtype == 'Microsoft Windows'
```

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript use indentation to identify the scope of functions, control blocks, parameter list, etc. The code you pasted contains no syntax error except that you passed a empty function to `jQuery` (which is the same as `$(document).ready`. It's more likely that the following code are all contents of the `document.ready` handler, because you can only manipulate the DOM contents when they are ready.

```
jQuery ->
  sev = $('#rule_severity').html()
  $('#rule_log_type').change ->
    logtype = $('#rule_log_type :selected').text()
    if (logtype == 'Syslog')
      $('#rule_severity')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>')
        .append('<option value="Alert">Alert</option>')
        .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
        .append('<option value="Error">Error</option>')
        .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
        .append('<option value="Notice">Notice</option>')
        .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
        .val('Information')
    else if (logtype == 'Microsoft Windows')
      $('#rule_severity')
        .find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option value="Critical">Critical</option>')
        .append('<option value="Warning">Warning</option>')
        .append('<option value="Information">Information</option>')
        .val('Information')
```